# C++ static library to be used in XCode

Tags: iphone, c++, objective-c, static-libraries

This is probably not a simple question so I am not looking for a definite answer but just some pointers to get me in the right direction.

I have absolutely no experience with C/C++ but have good knowledge of Objective-C. I also don't know much about different compilers and architectures so please be nice if I am talking stupid :)

I have some MatLab code that needs to be ported to Objective-C to run on an iPhone application. My first tentative path to get this done would be to check if MatLab can export the code as a static C/C++ library that I can call from within my Objective-C code.

This seems to be the case but I am not entirely sure what to do next, and what things I need to keep in mind when compiling the library on the MatLab side (i.e. architecture, compatibility, PC vs Mac, etc).

I have been provided with a .DLL and .LIB files which I believe are Windows compiled so they will not be useful for me, is this correct? From working with previous static libraries I can see they all have a .a extension - what do I need to do to get one that is compatible with the iPhone architecture?

And once I get the library compiled, how to I import and use it within my project? Will I just be able to call the public methods directly from within my code?

What else do I need to know or be aware of?

Any help is very much appreciated!

Thanks,

Rog

Comment: It sounds like you indeed have windows binaries. They are of little help to you unless you are prepared to delve into PC-compatible machine code/assembler. You really need the source code to get started.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Static libraries contain binary code tailored for some specific operating system and platform. That means that it will use the OS to internally acquire memory (if it uses dynamic memory) or to perform any other OS specific operation (logging, output).

Even if the generated code was completely OS-agnostic (basic math could be implemented without OS support), the platform is completely different, matlab will generate code for an intel platform and the iPhone runs in an ARM architecture, with a different instruction set calling conventions...

Unless matlab is able to generate static libraries for the iPhone or at the very least for an ARM platform and make it OS-agnostic, you are out of luck.